# Configuring jdbc-pool (tomcat 7)

Tags: tomcat7

i'm having some problems with tomcat 7 for configuring jdbc-pool : i`ve tried to follow this example: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency

so i have:

conf/server.xml

```
 <GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            name="jdbc/DB"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
            username="user"
            password="password"
/>
 </GlobalNamingResources>
```

conf/context.xml

```
<Context>
  <ResourceLink type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                name="jdbc/LocalDB"
                global="jdbc/DB"
/>
 <Context>
```

and when i try to do this:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource datasource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/LocalDB");
Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
```

i keep getting this error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:803)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
```

pls help
tnx

Comment: The original link is now gone.  But it was recorded by the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180521112213/http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency

Answer (score 3):

```
<Context>  <ResourceLink type="javax.sql.DataSource"  name="jdbc/LocalDB" global="jdbc/DB"/>
```

replace that `name="jdbc/LocalDB"`   with `name="jdbc/DB"`   in your context.xml
and

```
(DataSource)envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/DB");
```

[the second line of code is redundant].

Answer (score 2):

Change the Following line in server.xml
use type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" instead of type="javax.sql.DataSource"

and use (DataSource)envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/LocalDB") instead of 
DataSource)envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/DB") in your program, then you will get DBConnectoin.

Answer (score 1):

conf/server.xml and conf/context.xml...

do you have it inside tomcat installation prefix? on eclipse i have my context inside WebContent/META-INF, and server.xml inside Server project; on resulting war context.xml got inside the correct META-INF

in the end i have everything like your configs, except that i don't know where you're placing that context.xml.

also, i've made as @Henry suggested too, but with some luck your problem is just the location of context.xml